# Fail to deploy to an android device using 'ionic build android'

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

ionic build android failed on mac :(

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+.
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v13:23+.
```

Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.006 secs
/Users/Rain/Desktop/hc/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/Rain/Desktop/hc/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/Rain/Desktop/hc/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/Rain/Desktop/hc/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/Rain/Desktop/hc/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try to Delete the Platform Folder for Android and build again,so that it will create a new one

Comment: you need to add android support library